# NoSuchMethodError in TransferManager

Tags: java, amazon-s3, emr

I was using TransferManager for transferring my file from local to Amazon S3 using java.I am getting below error while running.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 
com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.TransferManager.<init>
(Lcom/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3;Ljava/util/concurrent/ExecutorService;)
```

I have used transferManager in my class.

```
ExecutorService execSrvc = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numberOfThreads); 
TransferManager tx = new TransferManager(s3Client, execSrvc);
```

Pom file looks like this.

```
    <dependency>
     <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
     <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
     <version>1.9.28.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

It would be a great,if anyone could help.

Comment: Please paste full stack trace.

Comment: how do you run your program ? are you sure to include the correct libraries in your path ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use version 1.7.4 of `aws-java-sdk`